# Setting values on repeater scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input within a repeater scope set up so that users can modify the value and see the calculated results on that value on that row - the intent is to have a spreadsheet like behavior.

I'd like to know what the best way to automatically populate the input box is, so that the field comes up set to a certain value with the model properly updated. I've set up a fiddle that tries to jam the number 4 into the value attribute here:

http://jsfiddle.net/BVRzh/

Where this is the template:

```
<div ng-app>
  <ol ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="a in arr">
      <input type="text" ng-model="testVal" value="4"></input>
      <span>Value: {{testVal}}, Times {{a}}: {{testVal * a}}</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
}
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: You can use `ng-init` : `<input type="text" ng-model="testVal" ng-init="testVal=a"></input>` , http://jsfiddle.net/BVRzh/3/

Comment: @Cherniv -- `ng-init="testVal = a"` :) -- http://jsfiddle.net/BVRzh/2/

Comment: @Cherniv -- Should post it, pretty sure that's the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ngInit`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) can be useful :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="testVal" ng-init="testVal = a">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BVRzh/3/

If i understand correctly , this is the only case when you can use `ngInit`. Citation from documentation:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit for aliasing special properties of
>   ngRepeat, as seen in the demo bellow. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.